# Excel MailMerge Export to PDF

Tags: excel, vba, mailmerge

Im trying to generate offer letters based on details provide and mail merge it. But i want my output in PDF Format instead of word.

Since it exports the file in word, i want that the final output that is generated is a PDF. But whenever i am trying i am facing with the same error.

Im getting System Error &H80004005 Unspecified Error.

```
    Sub cmdAgree_Click()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1

'    Sheets("DATA").Select
'    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
'    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
'    row_ref = Selection.Row
'
'    Sheets("Mail Merge").Range("D4").Value = row_ref

    Sheets("Mail Merge").Select

    frst_rw = Sheets("Mail Merge").Range("D6").Value
    lst_rw = Sheets("Mail Merge").Range("D7").Value

'    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    'Loop to check if the start row is greater than the last actioned row
    If frst_rw = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Start row can't be 1. Please check and update to proceed!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Sheets("Data").Range("A" & frst_rw).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Data to work upon. Please check the reference row used!!!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

'    If frst_rw <= Sheets("Mail Merge").Range("D5").Value And Sheets("Mail Merge").Range("D5").Value <> "" Then
'        MsgBox "Start from Row: Cant be less than last actioned row of data in the DATA tab." & vbNewLine _
'        & "Please check and update to proceed!", vbCritical
'        Exit Sub
'    End If

    'Loop to check if the last row to generate is greater than the total rows of data
'    If lst_rw > Sheets("Mail Merge").Range("D4").Value Then
'        MsgBox "End at Row: Cant be greater than total data rows in the DATA tab." & vbNewLine _
'        & "Please check and update to proceed!", vbCritical
'        Exit Sub
'    Else
    'Update the last actioned row for future reference
        Sheets("Mail Merge").Range("D5").Value = Sheets("Mail Merge").Range("D7").Value
'    End If

    'Loop though the start row and end row to generate the word documents for different candidates

    Dim wd As Object
    Dim wdocSource As Object

    Dim strWorkbookName As String

    On Error Resume Next

    'agreement_folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Agreement Template\"

    For x = frst_rw - 1 To lst_rw - 1
  ' For x = frst_rw To lst_rw

    'This if condition tackles the choice of group company basis which the template gets selected

    If Sheets("DATA").Range("AS" & x + 1).Value = "APPLE" Then
        agreement_folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Agreement Template - APPLE\"

    ElseIf Sheets("DATA").Range("AS" & x + 1).Value = "BANANA" Then
        agreement_folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Agreement Template - BANANA\"

    ElseIf Sheets("DATA").Range("AS" & x + 1).Value = "CHERRY" Then
        agreement_folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Agreement Template - CHERRY\"
    End If

        Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

        If wd Is Nothing Then
            Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0

        Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(agreement_folder & Sheets("DATA").Range("AL" & x + 1).Value)

        'Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(agreement_folder & Sheets("DATA").Range("AL" & x).Value)

        strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
        wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
        wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
                Name:=strWorkbookName, _
                AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                Revert:=False, _
                Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
                Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
                SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `DATA$`"

        With wdocSource.MailMerge
            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
            .SuppressBlankLines = True
            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = x
                .LastRecord = x
            End With
                .Execute Pause:=False
        End With

        Dim PathToSave As String
        PathToSave = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "pdf" & "\" & Sheets("DATA").Range("B2").Value & ".pdf"
        If Dir(PathToSave, 0) <> vbNullString Then
        With wd.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        If .Show = True Then
            PathToSave = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
        End With
        End If
        wd.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat PathToSave, 17 'The constant for wdExportFormatPDF


        'Sheets("Mail Merge").Select
        wd.Visible = True
        wdocSource.Close savechanges:=False
        wd.ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=False

        Set wdocSource = Nothing
        Set wd = Nothing
    Next x

    Sheets("Mail Merge").Range("D6").ClearContents
    Sheets("Mail Merge").Range("D7").ClearContents

    MsgBox "All necessary Documents created and are open for your review. Please save and send!", vbCritical


End Sub
```

Comment: Where in your code does the error occur?

Comment: Have you *tried* getting out a word document? I would try that first to check that the code actually works. Then maybe take the word document and try the "save as pdf" function (that's just my reasoning). It *could* be a bug in the VBA. Please update as to how it goes!

Comment: its not debugging any lines... Error window opens and it stops,

Comment: Word generates perfectly... but when i am trying to get a PDF output. it creates error

Comment: Another suggestion: remove the "17" and use the actual flag. It's a better practice

Comment: Dim PathToSave As String
        PathToSave = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "pdf" & "\" & Sheets("DATA").Range("B2").Value & ".pdf"
        If Dir(PathToSave, 0) <> vbNullString Then
        With wd.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        If .Show = True Then
            PathToSave = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
        End With
        End If
        wd.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat PathToSave, 17 'The constant for wdExportFormatPDF

i guess the above code need little fix

Comment: @HilaDG i tried it but still it give me the same error

Comment: Looks like a bug in VBA. Try to check if you can simply save a document as PDF, any document.

Comment: Yes, I can save the doc file generated to PDF :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code is non-trivial, so I'm not going to try to get it setup and working on my side.  Instead, I'd suggest adding a Watch Window, and check the results.  That should help you isolate the issue and quickly resolve it.

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/add_watch2016.php

Although error messages are sometimes misleading, it really should help you figure it out, or get close enough to post back with very specific information about what's going on there.